# Show data record using id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

### i got this error message

> Column 'id_siswa' in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT * FROM `siswa` `a` 
LEFT JOIN `pembayaran_spp` `b` ON `b`.`id_siswa`=`a`.`id_siswa` 
WHERE `id_siswa` = '7%E2%80%8B'
```

I have 2 table.

1.table 'siswa'
 structure(id_siswa,nama_siswa,id_tahun_masuk)

2.table 'pembayaran_spp'->
structure(id_pembayaran,id_siswa,jml_pembayaran,id_tahun,date)

I want to show data 'pembayaran_spp' by id_siswa.
so when i click detail on 'siswa', data 'pembayaran' is showed by id_siswa.

### My Controller

```
function detailtagihan($id_siswa)
    {
            $data['siswa'] = $this->M_keuangan->tagihansiswa($id_siswa);

            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('keuangan/v_detailtagihan',$data);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');

    }
```

### My Model

```
function tagihansiswa($id_siswa)
    {
        //$data = array('id_siswa' => $id_siswa );

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('siswa a');
        $this->db->join('pembayaran_spp b','b.id_siswa=a.id_siswa', 'left');
        $this->db->where('id_siswa',$id_siswa);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
            return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: `WHERE 'id_siswa'` is ambiguous. It needs to be `a` or `b` ` WHERE 'a'.'id_siswa'`

Comment: Hey, you got it fixed?

Comment: where clause doesn't know which column it should compare since the column exists in both table so you need to mention with the column name with table name like this `a.id_siswa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention of which table you want to use the column `id_siswa` in your where clause. As both of the tables are having a column with same name, you are getting this error.

If you want to use `siswa` then in your where condition write `a.id_siswa`

And if you want to use `pembayaran_spp` then in your where condition `b.id_siswa`.

Comment: Your welcome @CaturAnantaPutra. I am happy to help. Please accept the answer and vote it up. Thank you so much in advance for it.